# How to change SVG path's pivot point?

Tags: html, css, svg, path, pivot

I am trying to rotate my svg path from its top most point, but it's always rotating from its top left corner, unable to change the pivot point.
I also tried to change it from **transform-origin** property, but didn't work out.

Here is my codes ::

```
<!-- CSS --> 
    <style>
        .pivot {transform: rotate(60deg);}
    </style>

<!-- html -->
    <div>
        <svg style="width:30px; overflow: visible; margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 100px;" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 38.1 102">
            <polygon class="pivot" fill="#3F964E" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="19.6,0.6 0.6,10.6 19.6,99.6 37.6,11.6 "/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform:origin` will work...although different browsers (I believe) have different interpretations of the origin point.

For Chrome (in this instance) because the top point of the path is actually at the top/center:

```
.pivot {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin:top center;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpfestw0/3/)

Note that this is Chrome only...FF has a different result.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the svg transform attribute to rotate.

As said is the svg documentation :

> The rotate(<a> [<x> <y>]) transform function specifies a rotation by a degrees about a given point. If optional parameters x and y are not supplied, the rotation is about the origin of the current user coordinate system. If optional parameters x and y are supplied, the rotate is about the point (x, y).

example :

`<rect width="10" height="10" fill="red" transform="rotate(-10 50 100)" />`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform